# how to modify joomla mod_mainmenu

Tags: joomla1.5

HOW TO CUSTOMIZE JOOMLA MENU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google: "HOW TO CUSTOMIZE JOOMLA MENU."

First result: http://www.packtpub.com/article/customizing-menus-menu-in-joomla

Being serious again:
I know my answer can be considered to be mean. But have you actually searched for a HOWTO? Besides that, your question is not well elaborated.